# SimpleCov showing 0% coverage in RubyMine but works fine elsewhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-coverage, rubymine, simplecov

I have a suspicion that this is a local system configuration issue, but I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong. In my `spec_helper.rb` file, I have the following lines at the very beginning:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

I can run the following locally on the command line (which is exactly what RubyMine is running):

```
/home/scottj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -x /home/scottj/Source/foamfactory/api/bin/bundle exec /home/scottj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -r /home/scottj/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/RubyMine/ch-0/221.5787.34/plugins/ruby/rb/simplecov_starter.rb /home/scottj/Source/foamfactory/api/bin/rails spec
```

And it will generate a report in `coverage/index.html` that appears to be correct. However, when I run `api: spec` with coverage in RubyMine, all of my files in the app/ directory show up as "0% coverage". I *suspect* this has something to do with a `simplecov_json_formatter` that appears to be installed within my system gems folder, but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help with configuration so I can get back to a stable state where I can see code coverage in RubyMine?

Comment: have you looked through this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/code-coverage.html#run_with_coverage

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks, but, yes. I think it has something to do with pointing to the incorrect file(s) for coverage. I can see the `index.html` report being generated, along with some .json files that look correct, but RubyMine simply isn't showing the coverage in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I was *sort of* able to fix this by comparing with one of my other projects that had code coverage working successfully. What I did was remove the "spec: API" configuration that was a rake task configuration, add a new run/debug configuration of "RSpec" type and called it "Run All Specs", with the `spec` folder as the input folder.

Now, running with code coverage works as expected. It would be really interesting to understand *why*, though.